# Angular 4 Getting 404 not found in production mode

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I'm building an angular node app and am doing a http post request to signup a user. Its a chain of observables that gets the users social login information, signs ups the user, then on success emails the user. In dev mode everything works perfect, in prod mode, im getting a 404 not found. I also want to note that in development mode, some of my function calls in the observables on success are not being called. Its acting very strange and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my route controller

```
module.exports = {
  signup: function signup(req, res) {
    return User.create({
      email: (req.body.email).toLowerCase(),
      image: req.body.image,
      name: req.body.name,
      provider: req.body.provider || 'rent',
      uid: req.body.uid || null
    }).then(function (user) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        title: "User signed up successfully",
        obj: user
      });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
          title: 'There was an error signing up!',
          error: error
        });
      });
  }
};
```

and route

```
router.post('/signup', function(req,res,next) {
  return usersController.signup(req,res);
});
```

My service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private devUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/user';
  private url = '/user';
  sub: any;
  public user: User;

  constructor(
    private authS: AuthService,
    private http: HttpClient) {


  }

  signup(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/signup', user);
  }

  auth(provider: string) {
    return this.sub = this.authS.login(provider);
  }

  logout() {
    this.authS.logout()
      .subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
      }, error => console.log(error))
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

}
```

and my component logic for signing up using social buttons

```
  onAuth(provider: string){
      this.checkmark = true;
      this.uis.onSignupComplete();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkmark = false;
        this.thankyou = true;
      }, 2500);
    this.userService.auth(provider)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = {
          email: user['email'],
          image: user['image'],
          name: user['name'],
          provider: user['provider'],
          uid: user['uid']
        };
        this.userService.signup(this.user)
          .subscribe(user => {
            this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            let userEmail = this.user.email;
            let subject = 'Welcome to the rent community';
            let html = '';
            if (this.randomNum === 1) {
              html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail1();
            } else if (this.randomNum === 0) {
              html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail0();
            }
            let email = new Email(subject, html, userEmail);
            this.contactS.setEmail(email)
              .subscribe(data => {
            }, response => {
              // if (response.error['error'].errors[0].message === 'email must be unique') {
              //   this.uis.onSetError('Email is already used');
              //   this.uis.onError();
              //   setTimeout(() => {
              //     this.uis.onErrorOff();
              //   }, 2500);
              // } else {
              //   this.uis.onSetError('There was an error');
              //   this.uis.onError();
              //   setTimeout(() => {
              //     this.uis.onErrorOff();
              //   }, 2500);
              // }
              console.log(response);
            });
          }, resp => console.log(resp));
      }, response => {

        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

Here is the whole component

```
import {Component, DoCheck, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "../user/user.model";
import {UserService} from "../user/user.service";
import {UiService} from "../ui.service";
import {ContactService} from "../contact/contact.service";
import {Email} from "../contact/email.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.css']
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  user: User = {
    email: '',
    image: '',
    name: '',
    provider: '',
    uid: ''
  };
  signupComplete = false;
  signup = false;
  contact = false;
  error = false;
  errorStr = 'There was an error';
  checkmark = false;
  thankyou = false;
  randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);


  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const enter = 13;
    if (event.keyCode === enter) {
      // this.onSignup();
    }
  }

  constructor(
    private uis: UiService,
    private contactS: ContactService,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.signup = this.uis.onGetSignup();
    this.contact = this.uis.onGetContact();
    this.signupComplete = this.uis.onReturnSignupComplete();
    this.error = this.uis.getError();
    this.errorStr = this.uis.getErrorStr();
  }

  onClickAction(s: string) {
    this.uis.onClickAction(s);
  }

  onSignup() {
    this.user.provider = 'rent';
    this.user.uid = null;
    this.userService.signup(this.user)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        let userEmail = this.user.email;
        let subject = 'Welcome to the rent community';
        let html = '';
        if (this.randomNum === 1) {
          html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail1();
        } else if (this.randomNum === 0) {
          html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail0();
        }
        let email = new Email(subject, html, userEmail);
        this.checkmark = true;
        this.uis.onSignupComplete();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.checkmark = false;
          this.thankyou = true;
        }, 2500);
        this.contactS.setEmail(email)
          .subscribe(email => {
              this.onReset();
            }
          , error => console.log(error));
      }, response => {
        if (response.error['error'].errors[0].message === 'email must be unique') {
          this.uis.onSetError('Email is already used');
          this.uis.onError();
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.uis.onErrorOff();
          }, 2500);
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          this.uis.onSetError('There was an error');
          this.uis.onError();
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.uis.onErrorOff();
          }, 2500);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
  }

  onAuth(provider: string){
      this.checkmark = true;
      this.uis.onSignupComplete();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkmark = false;
        this.thankyou = true;
      }, 2500);
    this.userService.auth(provider)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = {
          email: user['email'],
          image: user['image'],
          name: user['name'],
          provider: user['provider'],
          uid: user['uid']
        };
        this.userService.signup(this.user)
          .subscribe(user => {
            this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            let userEmail = this.user.email;
            let subject = 'Welcome to the rent community';
            let html = '';
            if (this.randomNum === 1) {
              html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail1();
            } else if (this.randomNum === 0) {
              html = this.contactS.getAutoEmail0();
            }
            let email = new Email(subject, html, userEmail);
            this.contactS.setEmail(email)
              .subscribe(data => {
            }, response => {
              // if (response.error['error'].errors[0].message === 'email must be unique') {
              //   this.uis.onSetError('Email is already used');
              //   this.uis.onError();
              //   setTimeout(() => {
              //     this.uis.onErrorOff();
              //   }, 2500);
              // } else {
              //   this.uis.onSetError('There was an error');
              //   this.uis.onError();
              //   setTimeout(() => {
              //     this.uis.onErrorOff();
              //   }, 2500);
              // }
              console.log(response);
            });
          }, resp => console.log(resp));
      }, response => {

        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  onReset() {
    this.user.email = '';
    this.user.image = '';
    this.user.name = '';
    this.user.provider = '';
    this.user.uid = '';
  }

  errorStyle(): Object {
    if (this.error) {
      return {height: '50px', opacity: '1'};
    } else if (!this.error) {
      return {height: '0', opacity: '0'};
    }
    return {};
  }
}
```

I want to mention I am using angular-2-social-login for the social logins. Unsure why it would be calling 404 if I am using the /user/signup route appropriately.

Comment: Are you running your production server also in localhost?

Comment: How do I check/do that?

Comment: I just added enableProdMode() to my main.ts file. What should I check for?

Comment: Oddly Its only calling /user and not /user/signup . Ive checked my service that implements the http request and it is supposed to call /user/signup. It seems like the url is not updating when I push it to heroku